# Jest React Native how to test index.PLATFORM.js

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-native, tdd, jestjs

How can this be tested, to get jest coverage 100%

```
// @flow
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native'
import App from './src/App'


AppRegistry.registerComponent('app', () => App)
```

The files that are this kind are 'index.ios.js' and 'index.android.js'

Answer (score 0):

The default tests that come with a new React Native installation should do what you need as is.

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import Index from './index.PLATFORM.js';

// Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(
    <Index />
  );
});
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't work on this case and there are 2 issues with it.
1) the file is not exporting a component.
2) () => App is never called